# Windows takes forever on the welcome screen

Tags: windows-10, performance

It's been going on for a while now, way before the 20H2 update, windows takes forever on the welcome screen after you type in your pin/password (or whatever), the white dots just keep encircling in a loop, it used to take about 3-5 secs, now it takes anywhere from 20 secs to 2 mins (approx.). It also gets really sluggish right after the welcome screen and I can even see the audio drivers booting up (the volume has the red cross next to it for a bit), it does eventually get faster over time, is it something to do with Sysmain? I have an HDD, tried updating graphics drivers, I don't know what to do. Help.

I'm ready to give further information.

Comment: Is the Windows installation standalone or joined to a domain? Is your account a local Windows account or one from a domain or connected to a Microsoft account? Does the computer have full internet access?

Comment: standalone, connected to a microsoft account, full internet access.